# iOS issue. No matching code signing identity found. What the heck?

Tags: ios, certificate

I'm learning how to develop an iPhone app.

I've looked all over here, but the answers all seem to point to a lapsed distribution or development certificate. But I've never had either, so far as I know. I did the free registration with the developer program, and have worked my way through dozens of example programs, but am not yet ready to distribute anything.

Anybody else had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, OK, found it. Noob mistake.

I had typed "UITextChecker" below the @end in my AppDelegate.m solely for the purpose of using it as a link to the documentation. Forgot to remove it.

Good thing for me to learn, I'm sure everybody else here already knows better!